# Android. Posting data online and receiving them

Tags: android, networking, post, client-server

I have an android app. I want to share a status like facebook. Where users can share data and read other user's status.

Basically, I want my users of my app to share tips and read other user's tips.

To explain - I have an editText and I want to upload the user typed data from the editText to a server.

Also, I would like to load all the data saved by the user from that website and display it on my app.

From my understanding, what I get is, I need to POST data to a web server and I need to read data from the web server too. I have googled about finding tutorial, but I don't know if my approach is correct or not.

Do I need to have a personal website? Or is there some services or sites online that offers me that service. If I need to make a website for this, will DropPages of dropbox suffice?

I would appreciate, if you don't flag this question as inappropriate but would rather give me some fruitful advice that would help me.

P.S: I know lots of questions about this are asked but none of them covers explicitly what I want. All cover briefly or the answers are vague. So please, give me an answer like a pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a backend, there a lot of services you can use to get started developing.

Personally I am currently using parse, using this I can exchange all sorts of data (including the types you mentioned) between android/iOS apps and our wordpress based site.

This link was helpful when making the selection.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more

http://www.parse.com/ is what we went with, they make it pretty easy to get started.

Comment: Thanks a million. Using Parse got me started. And their tutorials are really good for beginners as well. Thank you